# How to use default (english) shortcuts on Mac in german language?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut

My problem is following: my Mac is localised german and I use an "ABC-Extended" keyboard layout (I do mostly programming and german puts important characters on annoying key combinations).

Anyway I notice App shortcuts are still for german keyboard.  Say in Safari back is `<C-Ö>` - however in the keyboard layout I need two key presses to achieve ö (`<M-u>` then `<o>`).  I manually set it back to the default mapping `<C-[>` however this is annoying.

Is there anyway to switch to the default shortcuts globally?